# Syntax issue while returning

Tags: assembly

I'm new to assembly therefore don't know much about it. I'm using MASM611 and DosBox 0.74. Currently, I'm writing a code in which I have to return from another label to a previous label. I'm not sure about the syntax at 'ret' either. Also during debugging, there occurs a problem at 'ret'.

the code is something like this:

```
label1:
cmp bl,bh
je loop
jmp display

loop:
inc count
ret
```

I want my program to go back to that point in label1 from where it jumped to 'loop'. Basically, the code asks for alphabets, and when I give it alphabets the program goes into forever loop (most probably, because it doesn't work). After debugging, it works fine till 'ret' but then it loses track or something.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problems (e.g.: what problem occurs? is it an error? if yes then what happens? (message, etc.)). Also what exactly do you expect to happen when `ret` is executed?

Comment: `ret` resumes execution at the next instruction after the one which called the function.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `ret` in conjuction with a jump to return back after the jump's location. The reason is jump instructions do not store the return address on the stack, which is required by `ret` to work.

Either use another jump:

```
    je loop
back:                -- see jmp below which jumps back here
    jmp display

loop:
    inc count
    jmp back
```

Or call a subprogram using the `call` instruction:

```
    jne no_call      -- skip the call if condition is not met
    call subprog
no_call:             -- 'ret' will return back here, as well as the jne above
    jmp display

subprog:
    inc count
    ret
```

Note that a more complicated syntax may be needed in your specific assembler in order to declare a subprogram.

Answer (score 2):

JCC / JMP doesn't push a return address for [RET](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html).  You'd need CALL for that, as Ondrej explains.  (And there is no conditional CALL instruction)

**A more efficient way to untangle this mess of branching**:

```
label1:        ;; jump to display after count += (bl == bh)
    cmp   bl,bh
    jne   display        ; jump straight there if there's no need to increment
    inc   count          ; preferably keep this in a register; Try to avoid memory for things you modify in a loop.
    jmp   display
```

It's normal for beginner's code to have way more instructions and branches than it should.  Besides running faster, simplifying the branching usually makes it easier to understand / read / follow for humans, which is definitely nice.